# The method parseString(String) is undefined for the type JsonParser

Tags: java, json, gson, jsonparser

My code was working perfectly before but now it is throwing out an exception,

The code :

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            JsonElement jsonElement = JsonParser.parseString(resultJsonString);
```

and the exception in the line `JsonElement jsonElement = JsonParser.parseString(resultJsonString);`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method parseString(String) is undefined for the type JsonParser
```

Any hints to why this is happening? It was working fine till yesterday!

Comment: Can you add imports?

Comment: These are the imports, import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

Answer (score 3):

This looks more like you've named your own class the same way as the `Gson JsonParser` class. So the compiler resolves `JsonParser` to your own class (`your.package.JsonParser`) and not to the `Gson JsonParser (com.google.gson.JsonParser)`. You may want to rename your class or use `com.google.gson.JsonParser` instead of `JsonParser` each time you want to refer to this class.

Another possibility is that the `Gson` library that you're using might be older than `version 2.8.6`. If this is the case, you've to upgrade your `Gson` lib. The static method `JsonParser.parseString` is added in `version 2.8.6`. Checkout the [change log](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

For **Maven**, use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

For **Gradle**, use:

```
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.6'
```

For **SBT**, use:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.8.6"
```

For **Ivy**, use:

```
<dependency org="com.google.code.gson" name="gson" rev="2.8.6"/>
```

For **Grape**, use:

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='com.google.code.gson', module='gson', version='2.8.6')
)
```

For **Leiningen**, use:

```
[com.google.code.gson/gson "2.8.6"]
```

For **Buildr**, use:

```
'com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.6'
```

Comment: JsonBuilderForUserFromDB --> This is my class name, so no improper naming convention.

Comment: it was working fine till yesterday, I decided to make a new package and move my code to new package under new class name which is JsonBuilderForUserFromDB

Comment: Have ever renamed your class to JsonParser by any chance in between? Do you want to try a clean build?

Comment: I can try clean build but never named my class to JsonParser. Should I clean build?

Comment: Sure, please try a rebuild and let's see how it goes.

Comment: It did not work, I used a work around, since it was basically for beautifying the JSON (from a single line to proper formatted JSON)

Comment: Cool, not sure what version of Gson you've, compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.6'?

Comment: It was 2.3, was it because of 2.3?

Comment: Ah, it's because of that, you've to upgrade your Gson library to version: '2.8.6'.